# Assign each element of a list to a separate variable in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have 5 data frames and need to add one column to each of them. After applying `lapply`, I need to reassign the `res_add` to each of the original data frames.

```
res_add = lapply(list(df_employee, df_sales, df_industry, df_domain, df_ip), 
                 function(df) {
                               df$label = rep("company", nrow(df))
                               return(df)
                              })
```

Is there any way to not write the assignment explicitly as follows?

```
df_employee = res_add[[1]]
df_sales = res_add[[2]]
df_industry = res_add[[3]]
df_domain = res_add[[4]]
df_ip = res_add[[5]]
```

If there is any way to assign the results like this, it will be more convenient.

```
df_employee, df_sales, df_industry, df_domain, df_ip = res_add
```

I want to scale this functionality to 20+ data frames. It's inconvenient to list each of the assignment explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood what you have in mind correctly you can use `list2env` function to turn elements of a list to objects in any environment. But before you use `list2env` to create objects in the `globalenv` it would be much better if you rename elements of the list so the resulting objects have meaningful names:

```
L <- list(a = 1, b = 2:4, p = pi, ff = gl(3, 4, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
list2env(L, envir = globalenv())
```

In order to name every element of the result of your `lapply` function we can use `setNames` function. Imagine `lst` is your result:

```
lst <- vector("list", length = 5)
setNames(lst, c("df_employee", "df_sales", "df_industry", "df_domain", "df_ip"))

$df_employee
NULL

$df_sales
NULL

$df_industry
NULL

$df_domain
NULL

$df_ip
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I just try and this works. The only step to add before the list2env command is to add names to the result list from lapply: names(res_add) = c("df_employee", "df_sales", "df_industry", "df_domain", "df_ip")

Comment: See my updates please. By the way @akrun 's solution is another great idea on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `assign`.  Loop over the object names, `get` the value of the object, create a new column 'label' and `assign` the object name with the value in the global environment

```
for(nm1 in c("df_employee", "df_sales", "df_industry", "df_domain", "df_ip")) {
 tmp <- get(nm1)
 tmp$label <- "company"
 assign(nm1, tmp)
}
```